# How to decode escape characters used in js and why it is not automatically decoding like in JSP's?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm working on the replace of quotes with escape characters but during render time in UI it was displayed as `&quot;`

Comment: In this case in javaScript you may want to use `\x22` instead. Like in `alert('\x22TEST\x22')`

Comment: Actually, We used the properties file to load validation messages to the application. When we use the direct message in jsp, it renders fine but through javascript file the message contains escape characters.